# 'Do not disturb' during a SECONDARY Google Calendar [Android 7.0]

Tags: 7.0-nougat, calendar, google-calendar, do-not-disturb

Under **Settings → Do not disturb → Event as scheduled** , I found the magnificent option to automatically turn on DND mode during events I'm in. Oddly I can only choose whole calendars, like general events in my whole Google Calendar, and not a specific calendar within my Google Calendar.

This makes this amazing feature unusable for me, since it cannot distinguish between important and casual events.

Does anyone of you have a solution?

Comment: Two ways I can think of, both not elegant. 1. Mark your events with replies and Configure *where reply is* to match. 2. Create a second account and use that for casual calendars and apply DND rules for primary account

Comment: And say that I would use 2. a second account – would that be an entirely new Google account, or is there some other lightweight option to create a second one I can select?

Comment: New account.... That's why I said not elegant

Comment: I guess that's fine. How can I add a separate new Google account to my calendars?

Comment: You would need to create a new account and use the calendars associated with it for casual events where you don't want notification. When you choose the DND option birth accounts would show up and you can select the one where casual events are **not** present